# Model binding is Failing for Ajax.BeginForm in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax.beginform

My View is scaffolding-generated for listing. The model for list is:

```
public class LogsViewModel
{
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string ClientIP { get; set; }
        public string StartDate { get; set; }
        public string EndDate { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

To filter the whole list, I am providing a bootstrap-modal form which has multiple input elements such as: category, clientip, date, and message. This modal's form uses Ajax.BeginForm in the following manner:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(
                       new AjaxOptions
                       {
                       HttpMethod = "get",
                       InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                       UpdateTargetId = "results"
                       }))    
                {
                    <fieldset>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Category:</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="Category">
                            <option>Information</option>
                            <option>General Error</option>
                        </select>
                        @*<input type="text" class="form-control" id="category">*@
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">IP:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ClientIP">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" id="startDTPicker" style="position:relative">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label" id="startDate">Start Date:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="StartDate">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" id="endDTPicker" style="position:relative">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label" id="endDate">End Date:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="EndDate">

                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" id="startDTPicker">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Message:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Message">
                    </div>


                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Show Results" />
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
           }
```

Then in the controller, I am trying to get these parameters (category=...). I have declared the ActionMethod as:

```
public ActionResult Index(LogsViewModel viewModel)
{
    //all the properties are null when the Ajax request invokes this method
}
```

What is causing the problem and what is the best way to deal with?

Comment: Use HTML helper or add name attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As i can see in your View code you don't have `name` attribute on all `input` tags. But you need them and they should match your model property names becouse they are using like keys when you post your values to server.

I mean you should change this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="ClientIP">
```

To this for all tags:

```
<input type="text" name="ClientIP" class="form-control" id="ClientIP">
```